# using local flutter engine when running add2app ios

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I downloaded the flutter engine and built it with a change I made. I can use this engine by running a Flutter only app using `flutter run --local-engine=ios_debug_unopt`. But now I need to use it with a Add2App implementation (flutter screen added to existing native iOS app). The question is: how do I configure Xcode to run the app using this local engine?

Answer (score 1):

We can probably add better tooling around it.
You can just run

`flutter build ios --local-engine=ios_debug_unopt --debug` or

`flutter run --local-engine=ios_debug_unopt`

in your Flutter module first. Behind the scene it'll set your configurations in the hidden file `.ios/Flutter/flutter_export_environment.sh` inside your module.

Assuming you're integrating via CocoaPods, when you run your outer iOS Xcode project, it'll pull in the values set in `.ios/Flutter/flutter_export_environment.sh`. The subsequent `xcode_backend.sh` which is also part of your build phase will then Do The Right Thing™️.